# Java NIO Charset Encode Decode

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, base64

Consider the following sequence of operations:

```
String pt = "abcd";
byte[] b64 = Base64.decodeBase64(pt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
ByteBuffer wrap = ByteBuffer.wrap(b64);
CharBuffer decode = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(wrap);

ByteBuffer encode = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(decode);
byte[] bytes = new byte[encode.remaining()];
encode.get(bytes);
String x = Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes); // "ae+/vR0="
```

Why are `pt` and `x` not equal?

Am I using these functions wrong? What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to encode some string into base64 format and decode it into the same string.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final String pt = "abcd";
  final byte[] b64 = Base64.encodeBase64(pt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  System.out.println(new String(b64, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));


  final String x = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(b64), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  System.out.printf("pt: %s -- x: %s", pt, x);
}
```

**Or**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final String pt = "abcd";
  final ByteBuffer buffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(pt);
  final byte[] base64 = Base64.encodeBase64(buffer.array());
  System.out.println(new String(base64));

  final String x = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(Base64.decodeBase64(base64))).toString();
  System.out.printf("pt: %s -- x: %s", pt, x);
}
```

**Result:**

```
YWJjZA==
pt: abcd -- x: abcd
```